# Oracle DB: Can one db file be shared between table space

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

Can one db file be shared between table space?

I am deleting temp table space as below,

1. Get all the files in  table space:

   ```
   SELECT FILE_NAME  
   FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES 
   WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'TEMPRM_TEMP';
   ```
2. Drop all the files in the table space:

   ```
   ALTER TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP 
    DROP TEMPFILE '/tmp/TEMPRM/create/TEMPRM/datafile/o1_mf_temprm_t_bw3yo9lv_.tmp';
   ```
3. Drop the actual table space:

   ```
   DROP TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP INCLUDING  CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
   ```

Are there any harm with this procedure ?

Comment: If you are dropping the complete tablespace, you don't need to drop the data files because the option `and datafiles` for the `drop tablespace` will do that as well. So all you need is step #3

Comment: I have tried that In ASM  is was not deleting it properly, while recreating  I was getting the error like {ORA-15005: name "rm/datafile/TEMPRM_TEMPFILE_1.dbf" is already used by an
         existing alias}

Comment: You need to create a new temp table space, make it the default temp table space with a new name, drop the old temp table space. If you want the name to be the same as it was before create a new temp table space  with the original name, make it the default temp table space and drop the temp table space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Oracle 11g Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/physical.htm):

> A datafile can be associated with only one tablespace and only one
>   database.

So you don't have to worry about losing data from another tablespace.

Comment: Thanks here we go,A tablespace in an Oracle database consists of one or more physical datafiles. A datafile can be associated with only one tablespace and only one database.